# Eigen::BDCSVD<Eigen::MatrixXcd> solver raises DGESVD error with MKL LAPACKE

Tags: c++, eigen, intel-mkl, lapacke

The following code works fine:

```
auto bcd_svd_solver = Eigen::BDCSVD<Eigen::MatrixXcd>(X, Eigen::ComputeFullU | Eigen::ComputeFullV);

MatrixXcd U = bcd_svd_solver.matrixU();
VectorXd s = bcd_svd_solver.singularValues();
MatrixXcd V = bcd_svd_solver.matrixV();
```

with `X` of type `Eigen::MatrixXcd` (a complex matrix).

However, if I use `-DEIGEN_USE_LAPACKE` option (to activate MKL LAPACKE), the following error occurs:

```
** On entry to DGESVD, parameter number  6 had an illegal value
```

According to https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-gesvd, parameter 6 is the matrix to be factorized (from data inside `X`).

Am I doing something wrong here or is it an Eigen bug?

Comment: And what is the data inside `X`? Maybe MKL is more strict regarding the content of the input than Eigen.

Comment: `X` is a square Hankel matrix, which is complex symmetric (not Hermitian symmetric).  But DGESVD should work for a general MxN complex matrix I think.

Comment: It is actually strange that `DGESVD` and not `ZGESVD` is called. This might be a bug in the MKL wrapper code.

Comment: Hmm.. that's true. The mentioned documentation says that it works with complex matrices but that's about whole `?gesvd`. I didn't notice that `D`, which is a specialized version for real matrices. This error makes sense now. I'll report that. Thank you!

Comment: Does your code work correctly with real instead of complex matrices? That would raise the likelihood that this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend switching MKL in a verbose mode. set/export MKL_VERBOSE=1 and show the output

Answer (score 0):

The LAPACKE_xxx functions call the fortran xxx functions for you without the first parameter.  The return number (-6 in your case) indicates argument #6 in the fortran call. It means argument #7 in the LAPACKE_xxx call.  So, LDA is incorrect.